# how to set upper small text in android TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, textview

I want to add small upper text in android textView

[image]

how would you implement this?

two textViews both `layout_below` the same element and then

make the second smaller?

or is there a way in one textView to put style to one word

(can be longer or shorter in other languages)?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by following code

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("2580<sup>TH</sup>"));
```

Comment: String str = "\"" + getString(R.string.some_string) + "<sup>TH</sup>" + "\"";  and pass this as argument as follow : Html,fromHtml(str);

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Android Layout framework, would put two textViews in side a Linear layout and that is it.

Another way, is making the small text as an image. Than you can add it to text view directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("YourRank:250<sup>TH</sup>"));
```

also you can do it like this:

```
String str=getString(R.string.rank); //YourRank:250
String str2=getString(R.string.superScript); //TH
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("+str+"<sup>"+str2+"</sup>"));
```

it worked like charm!

Comment: what kind of problem you face in localization system ?

Comment: it uses only plain strings. not html content

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SpannableStringBuilder` as fallows:

```
String text = "YourRank:250TH";

SpannableStringBuilder spannableString = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
spannableString.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), text.length() - 1, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

YourTextView.setText(spannableString);
```

Comment: but i have mentioned the last word (th) can vary in length, or even not exist in some languages